# My data can be approximated with normal distribution (multimodal). How can I find the reasons and explain this behaviour?

Tags: python, roc, gaussian-mixture-distribution, auc, discriminant-analysis

I use DeLonge method to compare two ROC AUCS. The result of it is Z-score.

Both ROC AUCs obtained from LDA (linear discriminant analysis) from `sklearn` package. The first one uses `eigen` solver inside LDA and the second one uses `svd` solver.

The dotted line is my data. The red line is N(0, 1)

[image]

Note: there is a minor jump at the point Z = 0.

Z = 0 means that classifiers did their job equally.

Z > 0 (Z < 0) means that the first (second) classifier did its job better.

Corresponding histogram:

[image]

This graphic shows the resuls of classification of 1 iteration (it won't be noticeable when compare 2 classifiers with this kind of plot so I just insert one). The amount of **normal** observations are *4 times* of the **amount** of anemia observations. The variance of **anemia** observations are *10 times* of the variance of **normal** observations.

[image]

The question in the title. How can I point at some facts and/or reasons that will explain the behaviour of my Z-score data (multimodality with separation in point Z = 0)?

Comment: What do you mean by the inherently contradictory phrase "multimodal normal distribution"?

Comment: As shown at the histogram, there are 2 modes (to the left from zero I have one normal-like dsitribution and the same goes for the right side).

Comment: That could be called a Normal *mixture.*  It's very far from being Normal!  Unfortunately, the question of "facts or reasons" is one of the very subject matter you are studying.  If you believe there might be a statistical component to the explanation, then you will need to provide the details of your classifiers.

Comment: Classifiers are basically built-in a ```scikit-learn``` (aka ```sklearn```), and the only difference is **solver**. I can prodive models of 2 data classes that are generated, but I don't really see connection between them and obtainable Z-scores (and its distribution).